# Adding Bootstrap tooltips into form label

Tags: html, laravel, twitter-bootstrap, laravelcollective

I trying to make `tooltips` into `laravelcollective`

```
<div class="form-group col-sm-4">
  {!! Form::label('exchange_id', 'Exchanges:') !!}
  {!! Form::select('exchange_id', [''=>'Choose Options'] + $exchanges , null, ['class'=>'form-control', 'id'=>'exchange', 'name'=>'exchange_id',  'onchange' => 'all_function()'])!!}
</div>
```

In the above select box, `{!! Form::label('exchange_id', 'Exchanges:') !!}` I want to put Bootstrap tooltips like, **Exchanges ?** : with question mark.
How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add attribute to `label` tag, `data-toggle="tooltip"` and `title="Exchanges ?"`

```
<div class="form-group col-sm-4">
 {!! Form::label('exchange_id', 'Exchanges:', ['data-toggle' => 'tooltip', 'title' => 'Exchanges ?']) !!}
 {!! Form::select('exchange_id', ['' => 'Choose Options'] + $exchanges, null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'id' => 'exchange', 'name' => 'exchange_id', 'onchange' => 'all_function()'])!!}
</div>
```

Need bootstrap plugin and use like it

```
$(function () {
  $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip()
})
```

Tooltips: http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/tooltips/

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/xL1vteoj/

Comment: I have already added `bootstrap plugin` but i unable to understand how to add tooltips on label `Exchanges:`.

Comment: Sorry, tv limit exceed!

Comment: try again @Jagjeet Singh

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176404/discussion-between-jagjeet-singh-and-kinnari-prajapati).

Comment: This works, but I have a blade variable {{$member->name}} that I'm trying to incorporate in the tooltip. It won't render because the form element is within {!! !!}. How can I get this variable into the tooltip text?